# Decouple a long running job into azure functions .. how to get overall status?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm studying how to split a long-running process into small pieces, keeping the global overview.
The current execution consists of the following:

1. calls to a first API endpoint which retrieves a list of items to process.
2. For each item of 1. it calls another endpoint and saves this data to the DB.

I've just created the first Azure function which retrieves the data from 1 and the second one that's called for each item. I structured it in a way where the result from 1 is pushed to a queue with a message that's processed by 2. in this way it's possible to call also the download of a certain item from a back office we have.

Now the main issue I've is to have an overview of the whole process and know when it has finished.
Before it was simple at the end of the for-each loop the execution terminated. Now pushing n messages on a bus means that I need some way to detect the status.

One possibility that I thought of is that when I start pushing the items to the message bus I also attach a guide (a kind of run-guid) and the total number of items send to the bus. I store this data in a temp table and then when each azure func finishes it writes the guid and its item detail to another table. I can know in this way about the advancement and possibly also the status of the single item. It would be great if with some "actor" also an email is sent when we have all the items processed but it can be done by another function which looks on the table.

Can this work?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a typicall fit for a durable function workflow with the [fan-out pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc#fan-in-out) applied:

[image]

Your fuction F1 calls to a first API endpoint which retrieves a list of items to process. Then, for each item call a function F2 with the item as an input. Once all items are processed you can terminate or call another function F3 to do something with the result, if any.

Once the orchestration function that calls F1 is finished, you know that all items are processed. An example is

```cs
[FunctionName("FanOutFanIn")]
public static async Task Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var parallelTasks = new List<Task<int>>();

    // Get a list of N work items to process in parallel.
    object[] workBatch = await context.CallActivityAsync<object[]>("F1", null);
    for (int i = 0; i < workBatch.Length; i++)
    {
        Task<int> task = context.CallActivityAsync<int>("F2", workBatch[i]);
        parallelTasks.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);

    // Aggregate all N outputs and send the result to F3.
    int sum = parallelTasks.Sum(t => t.Result);
    await context.CallActivityAsync("F3", sum);
}
```

Pleas not that having a result and calling F3 is completely optional and might not be needed for your use case.

Comment: Just to add, Durable functions uses table storage and storage queues in the background. So you don't need to create a queue and table on your own. You just need to take care of clearing the history on regular intervals. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=javascript#purge-instance-history